# Dynamic Programming: Can recursion with memoization work with any recursive solution or only solutions in specific formats?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, lis

I am reading about dynamic programming and was trying to solve the Longest Increasing subsequence problem.

I tried to come up with a brute force recursion approach where I generated all possible increasing subsequences and checked which one is the longest.

```
private int lis(int[] arr, int k, List<Integer> curr){
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=k;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(!curr.isEmpty() && arr[i]<=curr.get(curr.size()-1)){
            continue;
        }
        curr.add(arr[i]);
        ans = Math.max(ans, curr.size());
        ans = Math.max(ans,lis(arr,i+1,curr));
        curr.remove(curr.size()-1);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Here `arr` is the input array, `k` is 0 and `curr` is a list where I store the current increasing subsequence, `ans` is a global variable that keeps count of the longest increasing subsequence. I get TLE on this solution which is expected.

I know that this isn't the most efficient approach since I am using a list to keep track of elements and the problem can be solved without it. But I was still trying to apply memoization to this code as an exercise.

**I'm trying to understand if memoization can be applied to any recursive brute force solution *(or does it require the recursive solution to be in a specific format since there are several types of recursions like tail recursion etc)*? If no what properties should it satisfy?**

Can memoization be applied to the above algorithm to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Memoization can be performed as long as you're able to create a lookup structure that will recognize whether the arguments are the same so that you know when to return the previous result.

In Python a `tuple` is like a `list` except immutable and hashable so it can be used in a dictionary.  In other languages you usually have to do a lot more work to create a lookup based on elements.  What work that is depends on the language.  With the most common fallback being to create a string representation of your arguments.